# How to display value of object sent by node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I have question i try to put value from nodejs by init() in angularjs, later i put to $scope.product and when i try display i have problem with:
 node:

```
 return res.render('product/product', { title: 'Express', product: products });
```

angular:

```
<body ng-controller="productsController" ng-init="productView('<%= product %>')">
        <% include ../share/header.ejs %>

{{ product.title }}
{{ product.price }}
  </body>
```

controller:

```
$scope.productView = function (product) {
    $scope.product = JSON.parse(product);
    console.log(product);
};
```

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'bf' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 55 of the expression [productView('{ _id: 5950c8902a76e81b5cc56a6f, title: 'bf', price: 7, __v: 0 }')] starting at [bf', price: 7, __v: 0 }')].

Answer (score 0):

`product: products` - it's possible you are passing down an array of objects instead of an individual one. If that's the case, either change the `res.render` call on the server to pass only 1 product, or change the client-side code to expect an array and use something like [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need productView function, try simply

```
<body ng-controller="productsController" ng-init="product='<%= product %>'">

{{ product.title }}
{{ product.price }}
```